# Dishwasher pump does not stop after finishing the program

Tags: dishwasher

The pump is constantly running after the program is finished. I have to unplug the dishwasher from the electricity source to stop the pump.
When I put the plug back, the pump starts running again!!!
The pump stops running only when I tilt the dishwasher forward. Surprisingly, some water drains onto the floor when I do so.
Then the dishwasher is working fine again for a couple of washes, then the same situation happens again!

Any ideas what is going on?

Comment: Although the information is sketchy, I wonder if there is a float switch that still sees water and therefore keeps the pump on?  In which case, I'd check for obstructions and make sure everything can drain or be pumped out, and see if the problem continues.

Comment: There could also be a safety "bowl" at the device's bottom that collects water leaking somewhere out of the housing and makes a switch run the pump. If that's true I wonder why the machine finishes regularly instead of stopping right now.

Comment: sounds like it's behind on yearly maintenance. give a thorough cleanout and flush and if the problem persists, i 2nd the float switch blame.